# Python: Character encoding issue

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, web-scraping

I scrape data from a webpage with `BeautifulSoup`. For testing, I output everything to the console. Everything works fine there. Now I want to write the data to a file, but get the following error after some time:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u0107' in
>   position 57: ordinal not in range(256)

The issue seems to be this letter: **ć**

I use this code to write to the file:

```
 with open('data.txt', 'a',encoding='iso-8859-1') as f:
    f.write(text+'\n')
```

If I change the code's encoding to `encoding='utf-8'` the exception disappears, however the special characters in the written written file look wrong: *KuzmanoviÄ‡* should be *Kuzmanović*

Comment: I guess my issue was that the files I want to save the data to did not have the correct encoding. I created new files with utf-8 and it seems to work now. will report back, when i am sure.

Comment: If you save the file as 'utf-8' then you have to tell the tool that opens that file to use UTF-8, or set it to use UTF-8 as the default, if that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that the files I wanted to save the data to did not have the correct encoding. I created new files with utf-8 and it worked then.

Inititally, I should have ensured that the files created are UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `codecs` to write text with unicode as:

```
import  codecs
with codecs.open("data.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(text  + "\n")
```